# How to connect Insomnia to local Fauna database

Tags: faunadb, insomnia

I have a local Fauna DB and I can interact it with it using Fauna shell and using my own programmatic interface

However I am trying to use the Insomnia GUI and I cannot work out how to connect

This is my Fauna endpoint information

```
Admin endpoint: 127.0.0.1:8444
Replica name: NoDC
FaunaDB is ready.
Network Host ID: 172.17.0.2
Cluster name: fauna
API endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8443
API(plain) endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8445
```

And my Insomnia query

[image]

This gives an *Unauthorized* error

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Fauna uses Bearer token authorization. You can either set the `Authorization` header to `Bearer YOUR_SECRET` or set the secret in Insomnia's Auth tab.

[image: Screenshot of setting bearer token for Fauna in Insomnia]

I also recommend setting the header `X-FaunaDB-API-Version: 4`, which is the latest. Otherwise, [the API will default to v2](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/versioning#backwards-compatibility).

[image: screenshot of setting headers for Fauna in Insomnia]